# Statsmodel how to take results where P>|t| < 0.05

Tags: python, statsmodels

I used `statsmodel` `summary` to get information about my features and got the following result. [image]

How can I filter these values ​​so that I only get results where `P> | t |` <0.05

Comment: you could try loading this table as a dataframe and then use filter on the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the summary results in stored in the variable `summary_result`.

You could try this:

```
# To Convert the table to dataframe
results_as_html = results_summary.tables[1].as_html()
df = pd.read_html(results_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]

# Filter the df for P> | t | <0.05
df.loc[df['P>|t|']<0.05]
```

You could also get the dataframe directly if you are using `summary2` method instead of `summary` method from `statsmodel api`

with `summary2()`, we could just do like

```
df = results.summary2().table[1]

# Filter the df for P> | t | <0.05
df.loc[df['P>|t|']<0.05]
```